# Elasticsearch completion field not returning suggestions on searching with a token returned in _analyze api response

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I was trying to implement autocomplete functionality with elasticsearch completion field suggester.

Step1: Created a test_index:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_index?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"settings": {"number_of_shards": 1, "max_ngram_diff": 7, "number_of_replicas": "0", "analysis": {"filter": {"edge_ngram_completion_filter": {"token_chars": ["whitespace", "digit"], "min_gram": "3", "type": "edge_ngram", "max_gram": "10"}}, "analyzer": {"edge_ngram_completion": {"filter": ["lowercase", "edge_ngram_completion_filter"], "type": "custom", "tokenizer": "standard"}}}}, "mappings": {"properties": {"id": {"type": "integer"}, "name": {"type": "text", "fields": {"raw": {"type": "keyword"}, "suggest": {"type": "completion", "analyzer": "edge_ngram_completion", "search_analyzer": "simple", "preserve_separators": true, "preserve_position_increments": true, "max_input_length": 100}}}}}}
'
```

Step2: Indexed following document

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_doc?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "PANTOCID DSR CAP",
    "id": 1
}'
```

Step3: On hitting analyze api for "PANTOCID DSR CAP" I get ["pan", "pant", "panto", "pantoc", "pantoci","pantocid", "dsr", "cap"] tokens

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_completion",
  "text" : "PANTOCID DSR CAP"  
}
'
```

Step4: But when I'm doing a search with "dsr" I'm not getting any suggestions:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "suggest": {
    "egde_ngram_suggest" : {
       "text": "dsr", 
       "completion" : {
            "field" : "name.suggest"
       }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Why is that? I mean if searched text is one of the generated tokens then it must result in a suggestion match right? Am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What may be confusing is the `_analyze` step. While you did declare the correct analyzer, try to verify that field's tokenization by **specifically requesting that field**:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "field" : "name.suggest",              <---
  "text" : "PANTOCID DSR CAP"  
}
'
```

When you run that, you'll see that the text was n-grammed from the very beginning:

```
pandsrcap
pant dsr cap
...
```

and none of these token variations would start w/ `dsr` **and** ditch the `pan` prefix.

What this tells us is that the completion field works *properly* -- it's meant for autocomplete implementations, not for middle-of-the-text searches like you seem to aim for.

Comment: on hitting the api you suggested I'm getting this error:

Can't process field [name.suggest], Analysis requests are only supported on tokenized fields

Comment: Could not replicate.